# boto interpretation of the CLI command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Following Boto code prints me the undesired output I would to see the status of my EBS volume status not the mount point.

EC2 Reservation Structure:

```
object {1}
  Reservations [1]
    Instances[1]
      BlockDeviceMappings[2]
        DiviceName
        Ebs{4}
          Status
          DeleteOnTermination
          VolumeId
          AttachTime 

reservations = ec2Conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=[my_id])
for reservation in reservations:
    for instance in reservation.instances:
        for BlockDeviceMappings in instance.block_device_mapping:
           print(BlockDeviceMappings)
```

prints me:

```
/dev/sdf
/dev/sda1
```

Following AWS CLI command prints me the right status:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance myinstance-id --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].{Ebs:Ebs.{s:Status}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet will give you instance id , volume id and its current state. With your mount point you also get an boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping object , using which you can access its attributes as in the example below. Hope it helps.

```
from boto.regioninfo import *
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection

# AWS connect info
aws_access_key_id='########## AWS Access Key ############'
aws_secret_access_key='########### AWS Secret Key ############'
region_name='ap-southeast-1'
region_ec2_endpoint='ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'

# Connect EC2
aws_region = RegionInfo(name=region_name, endpoint=region_endpoint)
conn = EC2Connection(aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key,region=aws_region)

reservations = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=[my_ids])
for each in reservations:
    for vol in each.instances[0].block_device_mapping.items():
        print str(each.instances[0].id) + " " +  vol[1].volume_id + " "+   vol[1].status
```

some other use cases similar to this https://github.com/dvopsway/aws_scripts/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `raw` response then it looks similar to that:

```
            <blockDeviceMapping>
                <item>
                    <deviceName>/dev/sda1</deviceName>
                    <ebs>
                        <volumeId>vol-xxxxxxxxxx</volumeId>
                        <status>attached</status>
                        <attachTime>2014-04-01T02:23:54.000Z</attachTime>
                        <deleteOnTermination>true</deleteOnTermination>
                    </ebs>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <deviceName>/dev/sdb</deviceName>
                    <ebs>
                        <volumeId>vol-xxxxxxx</volumeId>
                        <status>attached</status>
                        <attachTime>2014-04-01T02:23:54.000Z</attachTime>
                        <deleteOnTermination>false</deleteOnTermination>
                    </ebs>
                </item>
            </blockDeviceMapping>
```

So All you have to do is just dig one level deeper then you are.

```
>>> import boto
>>> ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
>>> [ebs.status for  _, ebs in ec2.get_all_instances(instance_ids=['i-xxxxxx'])[0].instances[0].block_device_mapping.items()]
[u'attached', u'attached']
```

### Or using Boto3

If your goal is to get EBS Status that would "look" very close to the aws cli, you can do it using `boto3`:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.client('ec2')
>>> c.describe_instances(InstanceIds=['i-xxxxxx'])['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['BlockDeviceMappings'][0]['Ebs']['Status']
'attached'
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/snapshotStatus.py", line 22, in <module>
    print (ec2Conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=[my_id])[0]['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0])
TypeError: 'Reservation' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: for BlockDeviceMappings in instance.block_device_mapping.items():
(u'/dev/sdf', <boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping.BlockDeviceType object at 0x1f12dd0>)
(u'/dev/sda1', <boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping.BlockDeviceType object at 0x1f12d10>)

Answer (score 0):

Using CLI

```
response = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(
     ['aws', 'ec2', 'describe-volumes', '--volume-ids', Volume_ID, '--query',
     'Volumes[*].{AZ:AvailabilityZone, size:Size, Device:Attachments[*].{Device:Device}}']))

Volume_AZ = response[0]['AZ']
Volume_Mount_Point = response[0]['Device'][0]['Device']
Volume_size = response[0]['size']
```